# Can Sbt keep instrumented class files alongside non-instrumented?

Tags: sbt, scoverage

I go back and forth a lot between `coverageOn` and `coverageOff` and every time I switch, Sbt has to recompile modules all over again.

I wonder if, by putting instrumented class files under a different target folder we could reuse the already compiled instrumented ones when we come back from `coverageOff` and vice-versa.